# is it possible to set focus for element?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have two element on the page:

```
 <input tabindex="0" type="text" (keydown)="keydownInputSearch($event)" (click)="showSearchResultContent = !showSearchResultContent" #inputSearch>
```

And block:

```
 <div #searchList class="SearchList" *ngIf="showSearchResult()" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

Problem is when block `#searchLis` is exist I can not set focus back to `#inputSearch`.

I have tried:

```
 this.inputSearch.nativeElement.focus();
```

No errors, no effect. I suppose problem is that `#searchList` has `tabindex="-1"` and `#inputSearch`has less:  `tabindex="0"`.

But by defaul input should have focus automatically.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz so we can see what's going on

Comment: Okay, I will now

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-mijit5?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just focus on the input in `ngAfterViewInit`

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.inputSearch.nativeElement.focus();
 }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-1svrgt